# Removing HTMLCollection elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a collection of paragraph elements. Some are empty and some contain whitespace only, while others have content:

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<p>    </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p> &nbsp;</p>
```

I'm using `getElementsByTagName` to select them:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
```

This returns all paragraphs in the document. I want to remove all of them, so I'd like to run

```
for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
   paragraphs[i].remove();
}
```

but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined` errors. I think this is strange, but figure I'll try adding a guard and see what happens:

```
for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
   paragraphs[i] && paragraphs[i].remove();
}
```

No error, but not all elements are removed. So I run it again, and it removes *some* of the elements which weren't removed previously. I run it *again* and *finally* all of the paragraphs are removed from the document.

I'm wondering what obvious detail I'm missing here.

[Demo of the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTTce74gI3ndAG49ozir?p=preview)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem is that `paragraphs` is a **live list**. By removing a `p` element, you are also changing that list. A simple fix is to iterate over the list in *reverse order*:

```
for (var i = paragraphs.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  paragraphs[i].remove();
}
```

The alternative solution is to create a **static list** (non-live list). You can do this by either:

- converting the list into an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

  ```
  var paragraphs =
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), 0);
  ```
- using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

  ```
  var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  ```

You can then iterate over the list in regular order (using a `for` loop):

```
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
  paragraphs[i].remove();
}
```

or (using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop):

```
for (var paragraph of paragraphs) {
  paragraph.remove();
}
```

Note that `.remove` is a relatively new DOM method, and not supported in every browser. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) for more info.

---

To illustrate the problem, let’s imagine we have a node list of three elements, `paragraphs = [p0, p1, p2]`. Then this is what happens when you iterate over the list:

```
i = 0, length = 3, paragraphs[0] == p0  => paragraphs = [p1, p2]
i = 1, length = 2, paragraphs[1] == p2  => paragraphs = [p1]
i = 2, length = 1, END
```

So in this example, `p1` is not deleted because it is skipped.

Comment: Brilliant. I'd sorta wondered about this, but this way of getting around it wasn't apparent to me. And thanks for the `remove` compatibility tip. Fortunately, my audience will be on Chrome or latest Safari.

Comment: Regrading Op's title of removing only empty elements, add a condition: `if (!e.hasChildNodes() || (!e.innerHTML.indexOf("&nbsp")>0))...` *Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a2Hbn/*

Comment: @FelixKling I considered trying either of the alternatives beforing posting, but I'm glad that I didn't because while I feel a little silly for not catching it, I'm less likely to repeat similar mistakes later. Your answer is very clear, so hopefully it helps others too.

Comment: @abhitalks I actually want to remove all items as far as how I presented the issue, so my title was misleading given the actual problem. I just updated it to be more accurate, so thanks.

Comment: Your two-expression for loop is very concise, but I must suggest it confounds the example because it decrements on the first iteration, and the condition relies on the falsiness of the decrement evaluating to 0. On that note, will it delete the last element, at index 0?

For those who need it, a traditional statement for counting backwards would be: ```for (var i = paragraphs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)```

Comment: Thanks, worked smoothly. one thing I didn't understand what is the live list you mention for elements?

Answer (score 11):

The length of your HTMLCollection changes when you remove an item. A way to do it is to use a while loop

```
while(paragraphs.length > 0) {
   paragraphs[0].remove();
}
```

Comment: This will only work as long as you guarantee to remove **all** child nodes

Answer (score 5):

### Why this doesn't work for you:

The *HTMLCollection* is mutating (changing) while you are removing nodes, the length gets *out-of-sync* with the "real" length of the *HTMLCollection* array.

Lets say you have an array of 2 DOM nodes, and you are iterating it. it should iterate 2 times. The demo below illustrate this perfectly and i easy to follow:

**first iteration** - removes the first node and then `i` is incremented. 
**second iteration** - now `i` equals to `1` but the `paragraphs.length` is now also `1` because only one paragraph is left at this point.

This results in an impossible scenario where an array with length of `1` is asked to access an item at position `1`, and the only position available is `0` (since Arrays *start* from position `0`...)

Accessing a position which doesn't exist in an Array (or Array-like object HTMLCollection) is illegal.

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

for (var i = 0; i <= paragraphs.length; i++) {
   console.log(i, paragraphs.length)
   paragraphs[i].remove()
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
```

### Possible fix: *delay* the removal of the nodes

In the below demo the removal of nodes is made *after* **all** cycles of iteration has been made (`setTimeout` delays code execution), and the key here is to utilize the third parameter and pass the node which will be cached as the argument for the timeout callback:

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
   setTimeout(node => node.remove(),0 , paragraphs[i])
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant....</p>
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<p>    </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p> &nbsp;</p>
```

### Possible fix: on each iteration check the node exists

Also it's important **not** to increment `i` since the length of the array keeps shrinking, the first item gets removed on every iteration until no more items are left

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; ) {
   if(  paragraphs[i] )
     paragraphs[i].remove()
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

### Possible fix: I would almost always prefer a reverse-iterator

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

for (var i = paragraphs.length; i--; ){
    paragraphs[i].remove() // could also use `paragraphs[0]`. "i" index isn't necessary
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `removeChild`on it's parent to do that :

```
for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].parentNode.removeChild(paragraphs[i]);
}
```

---

EDIT : plnkr doesn't seems to run well from here, so I haven't tested, but it should work :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    var loop = function() {
        for (var i = 0, len = paragraphs.length; i < len; i++) {
            paragraphs[i].parentNode.removeChild(paragraphs[i]);
        }
    };

    console.log(paragraphs.length) // 7
    loop();
    console.log(paragraphs.length) // 3
    loop();
    console.log(paragraphs.length) // 1
    loop();
    console.log(paragraphs.length) // 0
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'd tried that as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8PnMQs8gsCXzo5mAUIl?p=preview

Comment: @MarcKline You're running the script directly into the head. That means it will run before the page (and it's content) is loaded. You have to do that in an `onload` event.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't work, and the last comment is not true. I load the script just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this was my solution:

```
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('level-size');
for (var i = 0, len = temp.length; i < len; i++)
    temp[0].remove();
```

**temp[0]** because each time I remove it, the hole table is pushed back one index.