# Remove by class name Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove all the elements from my page with a specific class name, but for some reason only the alternate class gets deleted.

The code pen link is here
https://codepen.io/miller619/pen/WoVpdE

```js
function prev(e) {
    'use strict';
    e.preventDefault();
    var getID = document.getElementById("zone");
    var removeXButtons = getID.getElementsByClassName("xbutton");
    for (var i = 0; i < removeXButtons.length; i++) {
        removeXButtons[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeXButtons[i]);
    }

}
```

```html
<div id="zone">
  <input class="xbutton" name="xbtn" type="button" value="&times;">
  <input class="xbutton" name="xbtn" type="button" value="&times;">
  <input class="xbutton" name="xbtn" type="button" value="&times;">
</div>
<div id="pbtn" > <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-preview" onclick="prev(event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Delete all</a> </div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Loop backwards instead of forwards. When you remove an element, the loop index of every element after it changes.

Comment: Because once you remove a child, the index of the remaining children also changes on each iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing HTMLCollection elements from the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988982/removing-htmlcollection-elements-from-the-dom)

Comment: looping backwards made it work.. thanks a lot everyone....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of for loop and it'll work. Problem is as you remove an element from array, the order of element changes. Traversing the array backwards wont give you this problem.

```
function prev(e) {
    'use strict';
    e.preventDefault();
    var getID = document.getElementById("zone");
    var removeXButtons = getID.getElementsByClassName("xbutton");
    for (var i = removeXButtons.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        removeXButtons[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeXButtons[i]);
    }
} 
}
```

If you want to loop forwards you can do this,

```
function prev(e) {
        'use strict';
        e.preventDefault();
        var getID = document.getElementById("zone");
        var removeXButtons = getID.getElementsByClassName("xbutton");
        for (var i = 0; i < removeXButtons.length-1 ; i++) {
            removeXButtons[i].parentNode.removeChild(removeXButtons[i]);
            i--;
        }
    } 
    }
```

Comment: `while(removeXButtons.length) removeXButtons[0].parentNode.removeChild(removeXButtons[0]);`