# Javascript: Why is FOR loop skipping every other match?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I'm currently getting 5 results from my `.getElementsByName()` query, and looping though them proceeds as expected when throwing a simple `alert()`, but as soon as I try to set new names for those results, it's skipping my second and fourth matches.

**SOURCE:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=1 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=2 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=3 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=4 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=5 />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
</form>
```

When I try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var fields = document.getElementsByName("target");

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        alert( fields[i].value );
    }
}
```

It throws an alert for all five values.

HOWEVER, when I try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].name = 'target[]';
}
```

it only renames every other one (0,2,4).

What am I missing?

Comment: And, please feel free to share if there's a more succinct/elegant way to rename the target elements.

Comment: It appears to be retrieving them on every pass, since the second time the second with that name would be now what originally was the third element.

Comment: `getElementsByName` is a live list, changing the name removes it from the list

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll()` which returns a *static* `NodeList` according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) as opposed to a *live* node list returned by `document.getElementsByName()`.

Comment: Ahhh, _live_ list! Thanks-a-bunch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Isaac regarding the cause - but I have an alternate solution if you change to a querySelectorAll as below - it will work for all checkboxes and apply the altered name[].

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll("[name='target']");
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
         fields[i].name = 'target[]';
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=1 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=2 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=3 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=4 />
    <input type="checkbox" name="target" value=5 />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (var i = fields.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    fields[i].name = 'target[]';
}
```

I think this is because when you change the fields name, and `document::getElementsByName` is a "magical" list (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647304/remove-by-class-name-javascript)), it is removed from the list you're iterating through if you change its name.