# Why does remove() skips every second in array

Tags: javascript

I have like 100 spans on page and with javascript I want to remove all of them:

```
function removeElements(){

    var elementss = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for(var i=0; i<elementss.length; i++){

        elementss[i].remove();

    }

}
```

lets say I have 10 spans

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

When I click remove button I get this:

2,4,6,8,10

It works if I want to change innetHTML, or value or something else but for remove() it doesn't work....

Comment: in which browser?

Comment: Chrome, I know it doesn work in IE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a [live elements collection(`HTMLCollection`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) it will automatically get updated when you are removing element so it will skip some elements since element position is getting updated.

So remove elements in reverse order to avoid skipping the element in the easiest way.

```
var i = elementss.length;

while(i--){
  elementss[i].remove();
}
```

---

For IE support use [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method.

```
var i = elementss.length;

while(i--){
  elementss[i].parentNode.removeChild(elementss[i]);
}
```

Comment: I will accept but I didn't know what to type and the answer is here as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988982/removing-htmlcollection-elements-from-the-dom

Answer (score 2):

when you remove the first element, the original second element is then the first, the third is the second and so on.

In order to remove all the elements, is

```
for(var i=elementss.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  elementss[i].remove();
}
```

That will remove the elements backwards without altering the original order.

Comment: Friendly explanation.