# Code isn’t executed after removing rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wrote a JavaScript function to remove selected rows in a table and it works fine but when I try to write some jQuery to change color of some button it doesn’t work. I have no clue what am I doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="DeleteRow()" class="btn"> delete </button>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
        <td> 1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    function DeleteRow() { //this function delete selected rows from table
      var i, chkbx, td;
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); //table itself
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //rows in table-body         
      var numRows = rows.length; //number of rows
      for (i = 1; i < numRows; i++) { //in this "for loop" , I try to remove selected rows
        td = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        chkbx = td.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
        if (chkbx.checked == true) {
          table.deleteRow(i);
          --i; //each time we delete one row we decrease i      
        }
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".btn").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
      }); //this jquery wont work
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your document.ready is inside your function call, I'm guessing your function is called post page load, and then nothing will actually trigger the .ready function

Comment: `$(document).ready` isn’t the issue. If the document is already ready, it’ll work. It actually _does_ work if no element is deleted. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). `rows[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Right.When you click the delete button, then it actually triggers and re-colors the button... The reason is, the code for the document ready is INSIDE the delete button function, so it only gets called when the delete button is clicked. Good catch, @Culyx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing HTMLCollection elements from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988982/removing-htmlcollection-elements-from-the-dom)

Comment: @Culyx and Snowmonkey — this is not the issue. `$(document).ready` will run regardless. The mistake is that he’s mutating an `HTMLCollection` in a loop. The return value of `getElementsByTagName` is a _live_ list. That’s why a `for` loop running forward will sometimes be a few indexes ahead, in this case throwing the error that `rows[i]` is `undefined`. That’s because a previous element from that `HTMLCollection` has been removed and no element exists at the index `i` anymore.

Comment: @Xufox $(document).ready may run anyway, but the fact that another method has to be invoked is, at best, a poor coding practice. Good eye on the loop issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your loop causing an error, so I've fixed those, and moved your inline event listener to the JS file. Comments in the code. I also switched from jQuery to vanilla JS because there's no reason to use it if you're using vanilla JS everywhere else.

```js
// Grab the button and add an click event for DeleteRow
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener('click', DeleteRow, false)

function DeleteRow() { 
  var i, chkbx, td;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

  // When removing items from the DOM it's usually a good idea
  // to reverse the loop and simply use the length of the array.
  // That way you don't have to decrement the index manually
  for (let i = rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    td = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    chkbx = td.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    if (chkbx.checked == true) {
      table.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }

  // You don't have to use jQuery (it's a waste if everything 
  // else is native JS. Here we use `this` which is the element attached
  // the click event
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn"> delete </button>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
      <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
      <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: great . your code works perfectly ... but can you tell me what was wrong my "for loop" ?

Comment: This changes the button background even if no rows were selected / deleted

Comment: @AhmadReza, even though you were decrementing `i` the length of the array would always remain the same because you were using `numRows` (set to the array length) for each iteration of the loop. So either you needed to decrement `l` too, or just use `rows.length` instead which would automatically decrement when you removed an element.

Answer (score 0):

A short refined version of your code could be like below. This will only change button background if the row is selected / deleted.

```js
function DeleteRow() { //this function delete selected rows from table
  var i, chkbx, td;
  var table = $("#myTable tbody>tr input:checked"); //table itself

  table.each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  })
  if (table.length) {
    return true;
  }


}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#del').click(function() {
    if (DeleteRow()) {
      $(".btn").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    }
  }); //this jquery wont work
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="del"> delete </button>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
      <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" class="checkbox"> </td>
      <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have jQuery, why are you mixing it with plain js? You can do this in jQuery very simply:

```
function DeleteRow() { //this function delete selected rows from table
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
    $(".btn").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
}
```