# Appending all the tables in a div onto the body

Tags: javascript

i have a div, with 3 tables in it.

```
var x = tempDiv.getElementsByClassName("hiscore_table");
```

I know this for sure because when i console log it, it prints like this:

[image]

I make a new div to append the tables on

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    newDiv.appendChild(x[i]);
}
```

I then append to the body, but only 2 tables show. I debugged the for loop and its only running the loop 2 times. If i print x.length i get 3. Im not too good at debugging but when i append child it seems to be deleting it from the old div, maybe thats the cause.

Comment: perfect that worked. i need to look into the differences of a live list. thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re creating a new `<div>` and appending elements that currently exist in the DOM to it. This means that you’re *removing* those elements from the DOM in order to append them to the `<div>` (which is not in the DOM).

Next, the thing you need to know about [`HTMLCollection`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (the return value of `document.getElementsByClassName`) is that they’re a *live* list. This means that any changes to the DOM are immediately reflected in the collection.

So, `i` is `0`, you append the first element, your collection now only contains two elements.

Next, `i` is `1`, you append the second element *of your remaining collection*, which is the third element overall. Only one element remains in the collection.

Next, `i` is `2`, which is out of bounds for your now-one-element collection.

This is similar to [removing items from an `HTMLCollection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23988982/4642212).

There are a few approaches to solve this, like iterating in reverse order. But I prefer a functional approach:

```
Array.from(x).forEach((table) => newDiv.appendChild(table));
```

This converts the `HTMLCollection` to an array right away, so it’s no longer a live list.

Comment: There is also a [*forEach* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) of *NodeList* in newer implementations which is likely supported by all (or more) hosts that support *Array.from*.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, if you want to support older browsers without the need for pollyfills or similar (i.e. write robust, easily maintained code), you can use a while loop:

```js
while (x[0]) {
  newDiv.appendChild(x[0]);
}
```

Oh, another simple fix is to use *querySelectorAll*, which returns a static NodeList:

```
var x = tempDiv.querySelectorAll(".hiscore_table").
```