# Array length won't increment after being emptied and can't add a mouse event on an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mouseevent, htmlcollection

I want to make my own grocery/task list in JavaScript and HTML. I can add things to the list no problem, but I have two problems:

1. If I added items to the list, then press a "clear" button to erase everything in the list, it works. However, when I add things back into the list after clearing it, my console notifies me that my array is still empty, despite new tasks being shown on the screen.
2. My second problem is bigger. See, all my tasks are in what I thought was an array, but are actually an HTML collection. So, when I try to set an `onclick` event, it just won't run. I have no idea why and I tried using the following question: [Removing HTMLCollection elements from the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988982/removing-htmlcollection-elements-from-the-dom)
   . It didn't work. I tried using `item`, [HTMLCollection item() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_htmlcollection_item.asp). Didn't work. My final attempt was using `for(let thing of...` but still no results.

Here is my code:

```js
let listGro = document.getElementById("list");

let aButton = document.getElementById("add");
let cButton = document.getElementById("clear");
let tasks = document.getElementsByTagName("li");


aButton.onclick = function addItem() {
    let newThing = prompt("What do you want to add?"); // asking what the person wants

    if (newThing) { // checking if the user actually added something
        let newItemList = document.createElement("li"); //create item list
        newItemList.className = "item";
        let newItemListText = document.createTextNode(newThing); // create text
        newItemList.appendChild(newItemListText); // append text
        listGro.appendChild(newItemList); // append new element
        console.log(`New task added\nNumber of tasks in the list: ${tasks.length}`);
    } else {
        alert("You can't add nothing");
    }

};

cButton.onclick = function clearList() {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the list?");
    if (conf && tasks.length != 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
            tasks[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tasks = [];
    }

}

for(let thing of tasks) {
    //tasks[i].onclick = function removeOrEditItem() {
        /*let demand = prompt("Do you want to edit or remove the item?\nPlease answer with 'edit' or 'remove'\nIf this is a mistake, just enter nothing.");
        if (demand === "edit") {
            let editItem = prompt("What is your new thing?");
            tasks[i].innerHTML = editItem;
        } else if (demand === "remove") {
            tasks[i].splice(i, 1);
        }
        console.log("clicked");
    };*/
    
    // The thing above was a previous attempt with for(let i; i< items.length... you can work with that or below.
    thing.onclick = function removeTask() {
        thing.style.display = "none";
        console.log("removed");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Website template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Grocery lists manager</h1>
        <h2>Welcome! here you can manage your grocery list!</h2>
        <ul id = "list"><span>List:</span></ul>
        <button id = "add">Add</button>
        <button id = "clear">Clear list</button>
    </body>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, could you highlights and explain the expected behaviour ? :)

Comment: in a comment or redo question?

Comment: To answer the question in the comments above, if someone asks for clarifications, then at minimum those improvements would be best in the question itself. You can add a comment in reply to say you have updated the post.

Comment: In relation to the meta-material that was in this post, I have removed it, as I think it can be counterproductive. [Read this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) to see why an excessively deferential presentation of questions can be the cause of a poor reception, instead of helping avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of tasks remains empty when you clear it, because you're overwriting an HTML collection with an empty array. You assigned `document.getElementsByTagName("li");` to `tasks`, which is a live collection. Reassigning `[]` to it will give it a non-live empty array. Instead of visually hiding the tasks with `tasks[i].style.display="none` and manually resetting the `tasks` collection, you should remove each task element from the DOM and let your live collection update itself automatically.

Removing a collection from the DOM has some pitfalls, but would typically be accomplished with something like the following:

```
while(tasks.length > 0) {
    tasks[0].parentNode.removeChild(tasks[0]);
}
```

---

Your event listeners are not being added because the code that adds them only runs once, when the script is loaded. And of course at the instance when the script is loaded, there are no tasks in the list. Add the event listener to the individual `newItemList` when it's first added.

Make sure that you remove the task from the DOM and don't just hide it.

```
 newItemList.onclick = function removeTask() {
     newItemList.parentNode.removeChild(newItemList);
     console.log("removed");
 }
```

---

Your complete JavaScript might look like:

```
let listGro = document.getElementById("list");
let aButton = document.getElementById("add");
let cButton = document.getElementById("clear");
let tasks = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

aButton.onclick = function addItem() {
    let newThing = prompt("What do you want to add?"); // asking what the person wants

    if (newThing) { // checking if the user actually added something
        let newItemList = document.createElement("li"); //create item list
        newItemList.className = "item";
        let newItemListText = document.createTextNode(newThing); // create text
        newItemList.appendChild(newItemListText); // append text
        newItemList.onclick = function removeTask() {
            newItemList.parentNode.removeChild(newItemList);
            console.log("removed");
        }
        listGro.appendChild(newItemList); // append new element
        console.log(`New task added\nNumber of tasks in the list: ${tasks.length}`);
    } else {
        alert("You can't add nothing");
    }
};

cButton.onclick = function clearList() {
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the list?");
    if (conf && tasks.length != 0) {
        while(tasks.length > 0) {
            tasks[0].parentNode.removeChild(tasks[0]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, so 1st problem solution works like a charm. Elements disappear and the "what I though was an array" can still increment. However, the console states this error when I clear the list :script.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.clearList

Comment: the second part works amazingly. Thank you so much @jla you are honestly a hero, even though this makes me feel dumb... But many thanks!!!

Comment: @FlipFloop apologies, there was a bug in my code. Clearing the collection was better done with a `while` loop. Answer updated and it should be fixed.

Comment: you're the best