# How can I remove HTML tags other than div and span from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to remove from HTML line all tags except div and span. How can i do this ?

example

```
const str = "<div><p></p><span></span></div>";
 remove(str)//<div><span></span></div>
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you trying to remove the tags or the HTML nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all tags excluding specific tags, you can use the following *regular expression*.

```js
const str = "<div><p></p><span></span></div>";
console.log(str.replace(/(<\/?(?:span|div)[^>]*>)|<[^>]+>/ig, '$1'));
```

Comment: This doesn't delete tags with the same start. For example, if you write  (?:s|div), it won't delete span tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `/<\/?(?!\bdiv\b)(?!\bspan\b)\b\w+\b>/g` with `replaceAll`

```js
let str = "<div><oz></oz><span></span><hjk></hjk></div>";

let str1 = str.replaceAll(/<\/?(?!\bdiv\b)(?!\bspan\b)\b\w+\b>/g,'')

console.log(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [`DomParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)'s [`parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) method to parse the string as (temporary) HTML. You can then delete the target elements with [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove), and finally convert back to a string with [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) if required:

```js
const str = "<div><p></p><span></span></div>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body;

var spans = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].remove();
}

var parsed = htmlDoc.innerHTML.toString();
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Careful with the `for` loop. `getElementsByTagName` returns a live collection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988982/removing-htmlcollection-elements-from-the-dom